# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{5^{2n-1}}{10^{2n -1}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to find out the sum (I just derived these from 2 + 0.5 + 0.125 + 0.03125 + ...):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{5^{2n-1}}{10^{2n -1}}$$

It's confusing me because it doesn't match $${ar}^{n-1}$$ the power by which $r$ is raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{a^k}{b^k} = (\frac{a}{b})^k$. Also $a^{2k} = (a^2)^k$, and $a^{2k-1} = \frac{1}{a} \cdot a^{2k}$. This should allow you to simplify it.

Comment: how will I find the sum of convergence from this if r is raised n-1 sum would be 1. But the given is 2n-1.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{5^{2n-1}}{10^{2n -1}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{5}{10})^{2n-1}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^{2n}=  2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac14)^n=2 \frac{1}{1-\frac14}$$